# Early exit gives blank page PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to clean up my code by "early exits" and keep getting a blank page everytime I use the return statement.
Should I move the php code to a seperate file?
Also I would be happy to get some tips of cleaning up my code.
Thanks!!

```
<?php
$capt_error = "";
$mismatch = "";
$name = $message = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    session_start();
    // validate captcha
    if (empty($_POST["capt"])) {
        $capt_error = "Fältet är obligatoriskt.";
        return null; // HERE, I GET A BLANK PAGE
    } else {
        if($_POST['capt'] != $_SESSION['rand']) {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $mismatch = "Inmatningen av CAPTHA är fel. Vänligen prova igen.";
        }
        else {
            // write to file but only if cookie is not set
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $time_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i');
            $data = "\n" . $_POST['name'] . ',' . $_POST['message'] . ',' . $ip_address . ',' . $time_stamp;
            $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            if ($ret == false) {
                die('Fel vid skrivning till fil. Skrivrättigheter saknas');
            }

            // set cookie
            $cookie_name = $_POST['name'];
            $cookie_value = $ip_address;
            setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, null, "/");
        }
    }
}
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="labb1.css" type="text/css">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Labb 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Laboration 1 - Gästboken</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" class="table-title">Min Gästbok</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bold">FRÅN</td>
                    <td class="bold">INLÄGG</td>
                    <td class="bold">LOGGNING</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    // open file
                    $f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
                    // while not end of file
                    while (!feof($f)) {
                        // split values with -
                        $arr = explode(",", trim(fgets($f), "\r\n"));
                        print "<tr>";
                            print "<td>$arr[0]</td>";
                            print "<td>$arr[1]</td>";
                            print "<td>IP: $arr[2]<br>TID: $arr[3]</td>";
                        print "</tr>";
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="border">
                <div>
                    <span>Namn:</span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Meddelande:</span>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="5"><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <?php
                        $rand = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5)), 0, 5);
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION["rand"] = $rand;
                        print "<span>CAPTCHA skriv detta i rutan nedan: </span> <span class='red bold'>$rand</span>"
                    ?>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $capt_error; ?></span>
                    <input type="text" name="capt">
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $mismatch?></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Skicka">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="red">*</span> är ett obligatoriskt fält
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: just erase line `return null;` in this particular case, if your expectation is to get `<link rel=...` in browser

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the return statement incorrectly in your code. The following is from the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was included or required, then control is passed back to the calling file.

What you seem to want to do is to capture the error message and then use it later on in your code - which is perfectly fine to do. Just set a variable with the error, continue your code and check the variables later on.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Could you show me an example?